# Problem with header imports in WSL Ubuntu. Using C in VSC on Win11

Tags: c, linux, sockets, ubuntu

i have installed WSL and Ubuntu.
if I want to run a code in C it doesn't compile because of the following error message:

```
In file included from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/sys/socket.h:33,
                 from sysprak-client.c:5:
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/socket.h:356:11: fatal error: asm/socket.h: No such file or directory
  356 | # include <asm/socket.h>
      |           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
In file included from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/sys/socket.h:33,
                 from performConnection.c:6:
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/socket.h:356:11: fatal error: asm/socket.h: No such file or directory
  356 | # include <asm/socket.h>
      |           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
```

It seems like there is a problem with the header files, and I am completely new to WSL.
Anyways I already did some research and I found this command:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r)
```

I ran it in Ubuntu and it throws this error:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package linux-headers-5.15.79.1-microsoft-standard-WSL2
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'linux-headers-5.15.79.1-microsoft-standard-WSL2'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'linux-headers-5.15.79.1-microsoft-standard-WSL2'
```

Any help is appreciated :)

--- Down below the new output

I get the following output running the command

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers
```

:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Package linux-headers is a virtual package provided by:
  linux-headers-5.15.0-1013-gkeop 5.15.0-1013.17
  linux-headers-5.15.0-1012-gkeop 5.15.0-1012.16
  linux-headers-5.15.0-1011-gkeop 5.15.0-1011.15
  linux-headers-5.15.0-1008-gkeop 5.15.0-1008.12
  linux-headers-5.15.0-1007-gkeop 5.15.0-1007.10
  linux-headers-5.15.0-1005-gkeop 5.15.0-1005.7
  linux-headers-5.15.0-1004-gkeop 5.15.0-1004.6
  linux-headers-5.15.0-1003-gkeop 5.15.0-1003.5
  linux-headers-5.15.0-1002-gkeop 5.15.0-1002.4
  linux-headers-5.15.0-1001-gkeop 5.15.0-1001.2
  linux-headers-6.1.0-1004-oem 6.1.0-1004.4
  linux-headers-6.0.0-1010-oem 6.0.0-1010.10
  linux-headers-6.0.0-1009-oem 6.0.0-1009.9
  linux-headers-6.0.0-1008-oem 6.0.0-1008.8
  linux-headers-6.0.0-1007-oem 6.0.0-1007.7
  linux-headers-6.0.0-1006-oem 6.0.0-1006.6
  linux-headers-5.19.0-28-generic 5.19.0-28.29~22.04.1
  linux-headers-5.17.0-1026-oem 5.17.0-1026.27
  linux-headers-5.17.0-1025-oem 5.17.0-1025.26
  linux-headers-5.17.0-1024-oem 5.17.0-1024.25
  linux-headers-5.17.0-1021-oem 5.17.0-1021.22
  linux-headers-5.17.0-1020-oem 5.17.0-1020.21
  linux-headers-5.17.0-1019-oem 5.17.0-1019.20
  linux-headers-5.17.0-1018-oem 5.17.0-1018.19
  linux-headers-5.17.0-1017-oem 5.17.0-1017.18
  linux-headers-5.17.0-1016-oem 5.17.0-1016.17
  linux-headers-5.17.0-1015-oem 5.17.0-1015.16
  linux-headers-5.17.0-1014-oem 5.17.0-1014.15
  linux-headers-5.17.0-1013-oem 5.17.0-1013.14
  linux-headers-5.17.0-1012-oem 5.17.0-1012.13
  linux-headers-5.17.0-1011-oem 5.17.0-1011.12
  linux-headers-5.17.0-1006-oem 5.17.0-1006.6
  linux-headers-5.17.0-1004-oem 5.17.0-1004.4
  linux-headers-5.15.0-58-lowlatency 5.15.0-58.64
  linux-headers-5.15.0-58-generic 5.15.0-58.64
  linux-headers-5.15.0-57-lowlatency 5.15.0-57.63
  linux-headers-5.15.0-57-generic 5.15.0-57.63
  linux-headers-5.15.0-56-lowlatency 5.15.0-56.62
  linux-headers-5.15.0-56-generic 5.15.0-56.62
  linux-headers-5.15.0-53-lowlatency 5.15.0-53.59
  linux-headers-5.15.0-53-generic 5.15.0-53.59
  linux-headers-5.15.0-52-lowlatency 5.15.0-52.58
  linux-headers-5.15.0-52-generic 5.15.0-52.58
  linux-headers-5.15.0-50-lowlatency 5.15.0-50.56
  linux-headers-5.15.0-50-generic 5.15.0-50.56
  linux-headers-5.15.0-48-lowlatency 5.15.0-48.54
  linux-headers-5.15.0-48-generic 5.15.0-48.54
  linux-headers-5.15.0-47-lowlatency 5.15.0-47.53
  linux-headers-5.15.0-47-generic 5.15.0-47.51
  linux-headers-5.15.0-46-lowlatency 5.15.0-46.49
  linux-headers-5.15.0-46-generic 5.15.0-46.49
  linux-headers-5.15.0-43-lowlatency 5.15.0-43.46
  linux-headers-5.15.0-43-generic 5.15.0-43.46
  linux-headers-5.15.0-41-lowlatency 5.15.0-41.44
  linux-headers-5.15.0-41-generic 5.15.0-41.44
  linux-headers-5.15.0-40-lowlatency 5.15.0-40.43
  linux-headers-5.15.0-40-generic 5.15.0-40.43
  linux-headers-5.15.0-39-lowlatency 5.15.0-39.42
  linux-headers-5.15.0-39-generic 5.15.0-39.42
  linux-headers-5.15.0-37-lowlatency 5.15.0-37.39
  linux-headers-5.15.0-37-generic 5.15.0-37.39
  linux-headers-5.15.0-35-lowlatency 5.15.0-35.36
  linux-headers-5.15.0-35-generic 5.15.0-35.36
  linux-headers-5.15.0-33-lowlatency 5.15.0-33.34
  linux-headers-5.15.0-33-generic 5.15.0-33.34
  linux-headers-5.15.0-30-lowlatency 5.15.0-30.31
  linux-headers-5.15.0-30-generic 5.15.0-30.31
  linux-headers-5.15.0-27-lowlatency 5.15.0-27.28
  linux-headers-5.15.0-27-generic 5.15.0-27.28
  linux-headers-5.15.0-1031-azure 5.15.0-1031.38
  linux-headers-5.15.0-1030-azure 5.15.0-1030.37
  linux-headers-5.15.0-1029-azure 5.15.0-1029.36
  linux-headers-5.15.0-1028-aws 5.15.0-1028.32
  linux-headers-5.15.0-1027-oracle 5.15.0-1027.33
  linux-headers-5.15.0-1027-gcp 5.15.0-1027.34
  linux-headers-5.15.0-1027-aws 5.15.0-1027.31
  linux-headers-5.15.0-1026-oracle 5.15.0-1026.32
  linux-headers-5.15.0-1026-kvm 5.15.0-1026.31
  linux-headers-5.15.0-1026-gcp 5.15.0-1026.33
  linux-headers-5.15.0-1026-aws 5.15.0-1026.30
  linux-headers-5.15.0-1025-oracle 5.15.0-1025.31
  linux-headers-5.15.0-1025-kvm 5.15.0-1025.30
  linux-headers-5.15.0-1025-gcp 5.15.0-1025.32
  linux-headers-5.15.0-1024-kvm 5.15.0-1024.29
  linux-headers-5.15.0-1024-gke 5.15.0-1024.29
  linux-headers-5.15.0-1024-azure 5.15.0-1024.30
  linux-headers-5.15.0-1023-intel-iotg 5.15.0-1023.28
  linux-headers-5.15.0-1023-ibm 5.15.0-1023.26
  linux-headers-5.15.0-1023-gke 5.15.0-1023.28
  linux-headers-5.15.0-1023-azure 5.15.0-1023.29
  linux-headers-5.15.0-1023-aws 5.15.0-1023.27
  linux-headers-5.15.0-1022-oracle 5.15.0-1022.28
  linux-headers-5.15.0-1022-ibm 5.15.0-1022.25
  linux-headers-5.15.0-1022-gcp 5.15.0-1022.29
  linux-headers-5.15.0-1022-azure 5.15.0-1022.27
  linux-headers-5.15.0-1022-aws 5.15.0-1022.26
  linux-headers-5.15.0-1021-oracle 5.15.0-1021.27
  linux-headers-5.15.0-1021-kvm 5.15.0-1021.26
  linux-headers-5.15.0-1021-intel-iotg 5.15.0-1021.26
  linux-headers-5.15.0-1021-ibm 5.15.0-1021.24
  linux-headers-5.15.0-1021-gcp 5.15.0-1021.28
  linux-headers-5.15.0-1021-azure 5.15.0-1021.26
  linux-headers-5.15.0-1021-aws 5.15.0-1021.25
  linux-headers-5.15.0-1020-kvm 5.15.0-1020.24
  linux-headers-5.15.0-1020-gke 5.15.0-1020.25
  linux-headers-5.15.0-1020-azure 5.15.0-1020.25
  linux-headers-5.15.0-1020-aws 5.15.0-1020.24
  linux-headers-5.15.0-1019-oracle 5.15.0-1019.24
  linux-headers-5.15.0-1019-kvm 5.15.0-1019.23
  linux-headers-5.15.0-1019-gke 5.15.0-1019.23
  linux-headers-5.15.0-1019-gcp 5.15.0-1019.25
  linux-headers-5.15.0-1019-azure 5.15.0-1019.24
  linux-headers-5.15.0-1019-aws 5.15.0-1019.23
  linux-headers-5.15.0-1018-oracle 5.15.0-1018.23
  linux-headers-5.15.0-1018-kvm 5.15.0-1018.22
  linux-headers-5.15.0-1018-intel-iotg 5.15.0-1018.23
  linux-headers-5.15.0-1018-ibm 5.15.0-1018.21
  linux-headers-5.15.0-1018-gcp 5.15.0-1018.24
  linux-headers-5.15.0-1017-oracle 5.15.0-1017.22
  linux-headers-5.15.0-1017-kvm 5.15.0-1017.21
  linux-headers-5.15.0-1017-intel-iotg 5.15.0-1017.22
  linux-headers-5.15.0-1017-ibm 5.15.0-1017.20
  linux-headers-5.15.0-1017-gke 5.15.0-1017.20
  linux-headers-5.15.0-1017-gcp 5.15.0-1017.23
  linux-headers-5.15.0-1017-azure 5.15.0-1017.20
  linux-headers-5.15.0-1017-aws 5.15.0-1017.21
  linux-headers-5.15.0-1016-oracle 5.15.0-1016.20
  linux-headers-5.15.0-1016-kvm 5.15.0-1016.19
  linux-headers-5.15.0-1016-intel-iotg 5.15.0-1016.21
  linux-headers-5.15.0-1016-gke 5.15.0-1016.19
  linux-headers-5.15.0-1016-gcp 5.15.0-1016.21
  linux-headers-5.15.0-1015-nvidia-lowlatency 5.15.0-1015.15
  linux-headers-5.15.0-1015-nvidia 5.15.0-1015.15
  linux-headers-5.15.0-1015-intel-iotg 5.15.0-1015.20
  linux-headers-5.15.0-1015-ibm 5.15.0-1015.17
  linux-headers-5.15.0-1015-gke 5.15.0-1015.18
  linux-headers-5.15.0-1015-aws 5.15.0-1015.19
  linux-headers-5.15.0-1014-gke 5.15.0-1014.17
  linux-headers-5.15.0-1014-azure 5.15.0-1014.17
  linux-headers-5.15.0-1014-aws 5.15.0-1014.18
  linux-headers-5.15.0-1013-oracle 5.15.0-1013.17
  linux-headers-5.15.0-1013-kvm 5.15.0-1013.16
  linux-headers-5.15.0-1013-intel-iotg 5.15.0-1013.17
  linux-headers-5.15.0-1013-ibm 5.15.0-1013.15
  linux-headers-5.15.0-1013-gcp 5.15.0-1013.18
  linux-headers-5.15.0-1013-azure 5.15.0-1013.16
  linux-headers-5.15.0-1013-aws 5.15.0-1013.17
  linux-headers-5.15.0-1012-kvm 5.15.0-1012.14
  linux-headers-5.15.0-1012-ibm 5.15.0-1012.14
  linux-headers-5.15.0-1012-azure 5.15.0-1012.15
  linux-headers-5.15.0-1011-oracle 5.15.0-1011.15
  linux-headers-5.15.0-1011-gke 5.15.0-1011.14
  linux-headers-5.15.0-1011-aws 5.15.0-1011.14
  linux-headers-5.15.0-1010-nvidia-lowlatency 5.15.0-1010.10
  linux-headers-5.15.0-1010-nvidia 5.15.0-1010.10
  linux-headers-5.15.0-1010-kvm 5.15.0-1010.11
  linux-headers-5.15.0-1010-intel-iotg 5.15.0-1010.14
  linux-headers-5.15.0-1010-ibm 5.15.0-1010.12
  linux-headers-5.15.0-1010-gke 5.15.0-1010.13
  linux-headers-5.15.0-1010-gcp 5.15.0-1010.15
  linux-headers-5.15.0-1010-azure 5.15.0-1010.12
  linux-headers-5.15.0-1009-oracle 5.15.0-1009.12
  linux-headers-5.15.0-1009-ibm 5.15.0-1009.11
  linux-headers-5.15.0-1009-aws 5.15.0-1009.11
  linux-headers-5.15.0-1008-kvm 5.15.0-1008.8
  linux-headers-5.15.0-1008-intel-iotg 5.15.0-1008.11
  linux-headers-5.15.0-1008-gke 5.15.0-1008.10
  linux-headers-5.15.0-1008-gcp 5.15.0-1008.12
  linux-headers-5.15.0-1008-azure 5.15.0-1008.9
  linux-headers-5.15.0-1008-aws 5.15.0-1008.10
  linux-headers-5.15.0-1007-oracle 5.15.0-1007.9
  linux-headers-5.15.0-1007-nvidia-lowlatency 5.15.0-1007.7
  linux-headers-5.15.0-1007-nvidia 5.15.0-1007.7
  linux-headers-5.15.0-1007-kvm 5.15.0-1007.7
  linux-headers-5.15.0-1007-ibm 5.15.0-1007.8
  linux-headers-5.15.0-1007-azure 5.15.0-1007.8
  linux-headers-5.15.0-1006-oracle 5.15.0-1006.8
  linux-headers-5.15.0-1006-gke 5.15.0-1006.7
  linux-headers-5.15.0-1006-gcp 5.15.0-1006.9
  linux-headers-5.15.0-1005-nvidia 5.15.0-1005.5
  linux-headers-5.15.0-1005-kvm 5.15.0-1005.5
  linux-headers-5.15.0-1005-ibm 5.15.0-1005.5
  linux-headers-5.15.0-1005-gke 5.15.0-1005.6
  linux-headers-5.15.0-1005-gcp 5.15.0-1005.8
  linux-headers-5.15.0-1005-azure 5.15.0-1005.6
  linux-headers-5.15.0-1005-aws 5.15.0-1005.7
  linux-headers-5.15.0-1004-ibm 5.15.0-1004.4
  linux-headers-5.15.0-1004-gke 5.15.0-1004.5
  linux-headers-5.15.0-1004-gcp 5.15.0-1004.7
  linux-headers-5.15.0-1003-oracle 5.15.0-1003.5
  linux-headers-5.15.0-1003-ibm 5.15.0-1003.3
  linux-headers-5.15.0-1003-gke 5.15.0-1003.3
  linux-headers-5.17.0-1003-oem 5.17.0-1003.3
  linux-headers-5.15.0-25-generic 5.15.0-25.25
  linux-headers-5.15.0-24-lowlatency 5.15.0-24.24
  linux-headers-5.15.0-1004-kvm 5.15.0-1004.4
  linux-headers-5.15.0-1004-intel-iotg 5.15.0-1004.6
  linux-headers-5.15.0-1004-aws 5.15.0-1004.6
  linux-headers-5.15.0-1003-gcp 5.15.0-1003.6
  linux-headers-5.15.0-1003-azure 5.15.0-1003.4
  linux-headers-5.15.0-1002-oracle 5.15.0-1002.4
  linux-headers-5.15.0-1002-ibm 5.15.0-1002.2
  linux-headers-5.15.0-1002-gke 5.15.0-1002.2
You should explicitly select one to install.

E: Package 'linux-headers' has no installation candidate
```

--- NEW ERROR after using sudo apt-get install linux-headers-5.15.0-58-generic

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libc6-dev : Depends: linux-libc-dev but it is not going to be installed
 linux-headers-5.15.0-58-generic : Depends: linux-headers-5.15.0-58 but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Comment: From https://askubuntu.com/questions/75709/how-do-i-install-kernel-header-files it lists the command you used. But, the 2nd answer suggests: `sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic` Or, maybe a partial version: `sudo apt-get install linux-headers-5.15.79.1`

Comment: thanks, but both options do not work unfortunately :(

Comment: You could use `apt list` to get a list of packages. Then, `grep` it for `linux-headers` and select ones you can do. Or, easier: `sudo apt-get install linux-headers` will list candidates and say _You should explicitly select one to install._ In fact, why not capture the output of that 2nd command, edit your question, and post it in another code block. Then, we might be able to guess the best one for you.

Comment: Okay ... From your `uname -r` we have: `5.15.79.1-microsoft-standard-WSL2`. But, from the `apt-get`, there is _no_ corresponding package. The "highest" is 6.0.x-y but that's "too new". The highest 5.15.x-y is 5.15.0-58 There are some 5.15.0-10xx but I think it's 10xx-vendor (where vendor is ibm, oracle, etc.) My best _guess_ ... Try `linux-headers-5.15.0-58-generic` This should allow you to try compiling things. The MS specific / WSL stuff might be in an MS specific repo that is _not_ enabled. MS is notorious for not following conventions.

Comment: I really thank you for your time and effort. I ran the command: sudo apt-get install linux-headers-5.15.0-58-generic in the ubunto terminal, but I get error msgs. I have added it also above. Do you think deleting WSL from my Laptop and reinstalling it might help?

Comment: Reinstall of ubuntu should be a last resort. I did a web search on: `apt --fix-broken` and got a number of sites. One of interest: https://superuser.com/questions/1386209/how-to-solve-this-dependencies-apt-fix-broken-install Please _do_ look at some of the others from google. There are at least 4 that seem to have good info.

Comment: Note that the package we tried _might_ be broken, but it may be a local repo cache issue (talked about in the link(s)). But, we didn't touch the libc related dev package!?